# Xaml Islands - Microsoft starter example not working for me

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am following the basic starter example shown here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands

I have followed it as closely as I can. I can get it working if I put my user control in with the UWP app (different to the example) but not as it is with the usercontrol in the class library.

Firstly, when I run the example as it is, I get:
"WindowsXamlManager and DesktopWindowXamlSource are supported for apps targeting Windows version 10.0.18226.0 and later.  Please check either the application manifest or package manifest and ensure the MaxTestedVersion property is updated."

The only solution I can find to this was to add a manifest file to the wpf project containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <maxversiontested Id="10.0.18362.0"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>

</assembly>
```

After that, I did not see that error, but when the wpf form loads, I see "Cannot create control of type ClassLibrary1.MyUserControl1", but no clues as to why.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong, how to find out what the problem is of know of any examples that do work?

Comment: Although I had set x64 for all the projects in the config manager, my solution platform was still set to "any cpu". I changed it to x64 and now get a different problem, in this.InitializeComponent, "Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.'
"

Comment: Hi, I tested the contents of the official documentation and built a XamlIsland WPF application to test. Even if I didn't set `MaxTestedVersion` in the WPF project, it still works fine. You can check if the WPF project you created is based on **.Net Core 3** and whether the minimum version of the UWP project and UWP class library you created is 1903 (18362). If everything is ok, please provide more code (such as how you create a custom UserControl) so that we can test.

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded my attempt here: http://belchamber.net/wpfapp1.zip Apologies if I did anything too stupid

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded your project package and I found that you missed a step.

It's the forth step in [Create a custom UWP control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands#create-a-custom-uwp-control)

> Before the closing  element, add the following XML to disable several properties and then save the project file. These properties must be enabled to host the custom UWP control in a WPF (or Windows Forms) app.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableTypeInfoReflection>false</EnableTypeInfoReflection>
  <EnableXBindDiagnostics>false</EnableXBindDiagnostics>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After you add this code to `ClassLibrary1.csproj`, clean up the class library and rebuild it, then everything will work.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change and it then worked. I'm a bit baffled as I have made many attempts and made that change many times. That particular attempt was made on a different computer, I will investigate further. But thanks for your support.

Comment: I notice I still get an error / warning in MainWindow.xaml under "xaml:WindowsXamlHost" : "Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.IXamlMetadataContainer'. WpfApp1 MainWindow.xaml 11" ,    although this doesn't seem to stop it from running. Do you know what this is about?

Comment: Hi, I checked the run log, but there is no related error/warning output. You can try to clean up the solution, if the problem persists, please provide more detailed recurring steps

Comment: I literally started with the solution I sent you, and made only the difference you suggested above. I have seen the same error every time I have attempted this, as has someone else in our software office.

Comment: And something else really strange, I extended the example to use a control from a vb project. For me, it literally works 50% of the time, alternately. First time I run it I get "Cannot create control ...", stop and run, it works and shows the VB control, stop and run, I get "Cannot create control ...",etc. http://www.belchamber.net/wpfapp1vb.zip

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your question, but there is currently no documentation for this issue. You can ask questions in the [Github issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues), thank you for your support.